# Allow community to accept the answer for those questions whose OP has left SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know accepting the answer is totally optional and is up to OP to decide whether or not he wants to accept the answer or not.

But when the OP has left SO, leaving behind some great question (which received several great answers), shouldn't there be any control given to the community to mark a specific answer "accepted"?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4201431/2828434) is one such example

Comment: We do not need op. That s what upvote are for!

Comment: The community already has *voting on answers*. It doesn't matter if the OP is currently active or not, their choice for what they accept is exactly that: **their choice**, including the right not to make a choice at all. They wouldn't have to change it when they are active on the site, why should that right go away just because they are inactive now? What if they became active again? Note that it doesn't matter in this argument that the account is now deleted.

Comment: Or put it differently, there is **no value** in setting an accepted answer mark on that specific post you link to. The best answer is already at the top, simply by voting.

Comment: As far as I can tell accepted answers don't actually provide anything other than 15 rep. It's upvotes that count, these give you rep and points towards tag badges. It wouldn't matter if the answer was accepted or not, that's specific to the OP, not the community.

Comment: **Alternate proposal**: Remove the accept mark. It's useless when the accepted answer is the best answer, and actively harmful when the accepted answer is not the best answer; let alone the fact that the OP is usually the least qualified to select the best answer (not in all cases, but most cases)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not necessary; and it would put words in the mouth of the person who has left SO.

"Accept" merely means that it solved the situation for the OP; not that it is the right answer. There are, in fact, several complaints here on MSO that users accept the *wrong* answer. We even have a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist) for having an answer that far out-scores the accepted answer.

If a user has left Stack Overflow, for whatever reason, accepting an answer on their behalf is pretending that they said that answer helped them. But we don't know if it did.

Just vote for the answers that you find helpful. You could even use a bounty to give an answerer some extra points - and then the bounty will show next to the answer, showing that somebody really appreciated it.

Answer (score 2):

On what factor can the Community accept the answer? Accepted answer means it is currently the best answer for the OP. And if there are multiple good answers and there will be in the future for the question which OP has left, how can Community decide which is the best answer? Not every highly upvoted answer can be chosen as the accepted answer.